# redirect all subdomains from http to https

Tags: apache, redirect, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I redirect all http requests for my subdomain to https by using following code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  Redirect 302 / https://subdomain.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now my problem is how do I do it for all subdomains.

For example http:subdomain1.example.com should go to https:subdomain1.example.com and http:subdomain2.example.com should go to https:subdomain2.example.com

How do I do it for all subdomains without having to create one virtualhost for all of them

**Update**

I found that RedirectMatch takes regular expression. Does anyone know how to do it using regex?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could add this to your server's `.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.example.com$1 [R=302,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The ServerAlias will allow the vhost to act as a wildcard, then you can extract the subdomain(s) from the host header and include them in the rewrite to https

Comment: this is a theorical syntax, but it cannot works without a signed certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this will work for me. But is there an easier syntax for doing this like "Redirect 302"

Comment: @drabo2005 - What? This is a VirtualHost on port 80 - i.e. it is only serving HTTP - no certificate is required on this host...

Comment: Certificate is required but not in this virtualhost.

Comment: @SuperEngineer - I don't think you can use `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` as they can only operate on the URL path, therefore you won't be able to query the host header

Comment: Your line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.subdomain\.com$` should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$`.

Comment: Note that you don't really need `RewriteCond`. Domain matching is covered by `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`. Any other domains can and should have a separate VH.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a simpler universal modification to the .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #...whatever you already have set up...

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Simpler and perfect!

Comment: This indeed solved my problem bigtime! Testimonial here.

Comment: Thank You! Thank You!  This just saved a novice Linux admin a lot of time and searching!

Answer (score 18):

As the Apache Wiki entry for [RewriteHTTPToHTTPS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) states,

> Using mod_rewrite to do this isn't the recommended behavior. See [RedirectSSL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RedirectSSL)

The vhost configuration for forced HTTP to HTTPS redirection - that also works with subdomains - is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    <Location "/">
        Redirect permanent "https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    [...your vHost configuration...]
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Explanation: Redirect and RedirectMatch normally don't have the variables (like `{HTTP_HOST}`) from Mod_Rewrite but if you use `<Location >` these Variables will be assigned.

`Redirect permanent` (Alternative: `Redirect 301`) will redirect with a http 301 code, because

> The 301 redirect is considered a [best practice](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543?hl=en) for upgrading users from HTTP to HTTPS.

Note: This config is based on [Wildcard Certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) for subdomains.

Comment: This does not work. URL to redirect to is missing, although I also believe that the rewrite is the wrong way to do as per your quotation and my research.

Comment: @PauloNeves that might have different causes, a wrong vhost configuration or outdated apache that doesn't support the <Location> directive. Try to set loglevel to debug to find out more: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel

Comment: @PauloNeves This solution worked in my hands.