# Apache2 redirect with wildcard subdomain

Tags: apache, redirect

I placed the following config in apache site `conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias *.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I have subdomains redirect without going to the main domain?

If I type `http://subdomain.domain.com/` it redirects to `https://domain.com/` but I want it to redirect to `https://subdomain.domain.com/`. I also want it to be a wildcard so that it works for all subdomains.

Is it possible **without** engaging the `mod_rewrite` module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirect all subdomains from http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059463/redirect-all-subdomains-from-http-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without mod_rewrite, but I'm not sure. With rewrite is very simple though:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```