# Apache: Permanent Redirect to HTTPS with Wildcard

Tags: apache, redirect, wildcard, virtualhost

I am trying to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS on my server.

I have certificates for `this.example.net`, `that.example.net` and `etc.example.net`, and I have my DNS accepting wildcards. I would like to permanently redirect HTTP to HTTPS using a wildcard.

I have tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.net:80
    ServerAlias *.example.net
    ServerAdmin mark@example.net
    RedirectMatch 301 (.*) https://$1.example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

but that doesn’t work.

I know that I can set up individual subdomains this way, but is it possible to use wildcards?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirect all subdomains from http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059463/redirect-all-subdomains-from-http-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

As [RedirectMatch Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) of Apache 2.4 httpd says:

> Syntax:   RedirectMatch [status] regex URL
>
> This directive is equivalent to Redirect, but makes use of regular expressions, instead of simple prefix matching.
>
> Example:
>
> `RedirectMatch "(.*)\.gif$" "http://other.example.com$1.jpg"`

Apache uses [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) compatible regexp's.

But normally it should be enought to use:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
```

Last but not least the important part: `Redirect` only matches **URL-path** and not the complete URL!

So you better add a `VirtualHost` configuration for every subdomain you are using.